# How to start using MongoDB?

Tags: asp.net, c#, mongodb

Can any one tell me how to start using MongoDB with ASP.NET and C#?

I have Visual Studio 2005 and I'm not using ASP.NET MVC.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Have you read the "Getting started" section of the [MongoDB docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home)?

There's even a page with various [C#-drivers for mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Community+Projects).

If you run into any problems after reading what you can find there I'd be glad to help, but if you don't have any problems and just need step by step directions, that site is definitely where to start. Stackoverflow (or any other stackexchange-site) is not. Come back when you have an actual question :)